# Kafka different ways to consume messages - when to use which one?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Messaging as well as Aapache kafka.I am confused on which Consumer API to use in which scenario,I saw that there are two client libraries available

kafka_2.11_0.10.11 and kafka-clients-0.10.1.1

The first one uses somewhat

```
ConsumerConnector consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector...
consumer.createMessageStreams...
```

and in second one

```
 KafkaConsumer<K,V> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
 consumer.subscribe(...
```

Does these two API server different purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the implementation in the kafka-clients library. The implementation in the main Kafka library are remains from an older implementation and will likely be removed in future releases.